Combinatoric equation involving three unknowns
Find $n\in\mathbb{N^*}$ and $p, q \in\mathbb{Q}$, such that:
$$(pn+q)\binom{nk+1}{k}+(qn+p)\binom{nk+2}{k-1}+(pn+q)\binom{nk+1}{k-1}=\binom{nk+2}{k+1}$$
for $\forall k\in\mathbb{N^*}$
Here's my progress so far:
$$(pn+q)(\binom{nk+1}{k}+\binom{nk+1}{k-1})+(qn+p)\binom{nk+2}{k-1}=\binom{nk+2}{k+1}$$
$$(pn+q)\binom{nk+2}{k}+(qn+p)\binom{nk+2}{k-1}=\binom{nk+2}{k+1}$$
$$(pn+q)\frac{(nk+2)!}{k!(nk+2-k)!}+(qn+p)\frac{(nk+2)!}{(k-1)!(nk+3-k)!}=\frac{(nk+2)!}{(k+1)!(nk-k+1)!}$$
$$\frac{pn+q}{k!(nk+2-k)!}+\frac{qn+p}{\frac{k!}{k}(nk+3-k)!}=\frac{1}{(k+1)k!(nk+1-k)!}$$
$$\frac{pn+q}{(nk+1-k)!(nk+2-k)}+\frac{k(qn+p)}{(nk+1-k)!(nk-k+2)(nk-k+3)}=\frac{1}{(k+1)(nk+1-k)!}$$
$$(k+1)(nk-k+3)(pn+q)+k(k+1)(qn+p)=(nk-k+3)(nk-k+2)$$
Now I am stuck. If this is true $\forall k\in\mathbb{N^*}$, should $n,p,q$ be given in terms of $k$ aswell? Or are there exact solutions for this problem?

https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959/14578, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1803/14578

So after expanding the brackets, moving everything to one side etc., we get:
$$k^2(pn^2-np+2nq+p-q-n^2+2n-1)+k(pn^2+2np+2nq+p+2q-5n+5)+(3np+3q-6)=0$$
If this is true $\forall k\in\mathbb{N^*}$, this means that $a=b=c=0$ given the equation $ak^2+bk+c=0$
$pn^2-np+2nq+p-q-n^2+2n-1=0$ (1.)
$pn^2
+2np+2nq+p+2q-5n+5=0$(2.)
$3np+3q-6=0$, or $np+q=2$
Substracting (1.) from (2.) results in:
$$-3np-3q-n^2-7n-6=0$$
$$n^2-7n+12=0$$
Which implies $n_1=3, n_2=4$
If $n=3$, then:
(1.): $9p-3p+6q+p-q-9+6-1=0$, or $7p+5q=4$
And also $3p+q=2$
So $p_1=\frac{3}{4}, q_1=-\frac{1}{4}$
For $n=4$, we have:
(1.)
$13p+7q=9$
$4p+q=2$
Which results in $p_2=\frac{1}{3}, q_2=\frac{2}{3}$
This implies that the condition $p,q\in\mathbb{Q}$ was just the result of the equation.
